# Indexing fields in 20 column table. Multiple conditions in one SQL WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, where-clause

I'm currently in the beginning of creating an app, which most important part is a table with 20 columns. This table will contain 3-5-7k records in the future. I have to combine multiple up to all the columns in one WHERE clause from this specific table for filtering purposes (less than, equals to, etc). 
The columns are varchars, ints, decimals and a date. 
So my question is if I have let's say 3k rows, my query will probably be a little bit slower if using all or more than 10 conditions in the WHERE clause, how do I decide which columns to be indexed. How do I optimize such a query. I know 3-5-7k rows are nothing for MySQL. The problem is that I have 20 columns in the table. Also I'm gonna be using PHP on the server if that matters at all.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After identifying the primary key, which should be a logical guess better than a performance optimization, you might add additional indexes to your table.

You have to keep in mind that mysql can use efficiently only one index at a time within a given table reference. The engine now has indeed the possibility of internally merging various indexes and then use them both but the performances are not so good. (see: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/19/multi-column-indexes-vs-index-merge)

What I suggest is you identify a set of queries that you're going to process (eventual joins with other tables as well), and then, if there are too many filtered fields, identify the most efficient fields for filtering out/in records. 
How to know what is the most efficient? A not null unique field for instance is pretty much a good candidate: mysql will filter this one out as fast as ligtning.

Generally the rule of thumb is to pickup an column/column-set that is highly differenciated: the values should not be repeated too many times, otherwise the index would be inefficient.

That's for a beginning.

regards

Answer (score 0):

Each table has a particular behavior. We must analyze each case.

In general terms, to make searches fast you should create an index in each of the 20 columns included in the where. In the other hand,  this would slow "inserts" and take up much space index.
Therefore, we should analyze whether or not add an index in each  one column.

Some tips to decide which column should not be this index:

- Avoid repetead column with value, the execution plan do not use your
  index.
- Avoid putting on index types: varbinary.
- Columns that have a high degree of update.